# Getters Setters in IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In here i'm going to set getters & setters to the IEnumerable filed.but it shows the error,

> > Cannot Implicitly convert type"System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerableto'System.DateTime'

```
    IEnumerable<DateTime> dateGroups { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateGroups
    {
        get { return dateGroups; }
        set { dateGroups = value; }
    }
```

Comment: `dateGroups` is `IEnumerable<DateTime>` and `DateGroups` is `DateTime`, so you simply can't assign one to another.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateGroups?

Comment: `DateTime` is a single value; you are trying to return/assign `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, which is a *sequence* of values (could be 0, 1, or many values - or the sequence could itself be `null`); what do you *want it to do* here? take the first? the last? the earliest? I have a bunch of dates (but I'm not telling you how many): which do you want?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to get/set the enumerable or get set individual items in it?

Comment: why you don't use a field for `dateGroups`?

Comment: @voo What would be the point? There already is a `IEnumerable<DateTime> dateGroups`. I think the solution is more something like `return dateGroups.FirstOrDefault();` and `dateGroups = new DateTime[] { value };`, although that wouldn't be very smart either...

Comment: @Nolonar It depends on what OP want. If he wants to get a single element from your collection, you should use  linq, no need to put it in prop signature of property. If you want to have a property, which is selected and set from your collection by some rules, you should update your setter by specifing this rule to dateGroups to select single value, and update getter (but i can hardly imagine what logic you can use in your getter). It really depends on many things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dateGroups is an IEnumerable of type DateTime, the DateGroups property is of type DateTime.

Do you want a list of dates or just a single one?

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateGroups { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateGroups
{
    get { return dateGroups; }
    set { dateGroups = value; }
}
```

Not enturely sure what you are trying to do here, maybe try something simpler like

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateGroups { get; set; }
```

This will achieve what you want (assuming you are trying to make dategroups an ienumerable of date, and not a single date.

Answer (score 2):

An `IEnumerable<DateTime>` is not a single `DateTime`, that's the reason for the compiler error.

So this works:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateGroups { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateGroups
{
    get { return dateGroups; }
    set { dateGroups = value; }
}
```

`IEnumerable<T>` is the interface that all collection types implement.